# Options for setting up and starting cassandra for production

Tags: cassandra

I have a business case for which we choose to pick Cassandra as NOSQL-DB, But we are stuck with aspect of setting up Cassandra, Any insights over what are the setup options available and what to choose is appreciated.

As of now the options i knew are
1)installing Cassandra on ec2 instance(which i believe is not a production ready option)
2)using a AWS managed Cassandra service

Is there any other ways, Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got the information from but they're not correct.

Thousands of companies have Cassandra deployed in production not just on EC2 instances but also GCP, Azure and other public clouds. It is also possible to deploy Cassandra on your own premises, private clouds and even hybrids -- any combination of on-premise + public cloud + private cloud.

If you don't have experience with installing/managing a Cassandra cluster, you can try [Astra DB](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) which is a Cassandra-as-a-service running on AWS, GCP and/or Azure. There's a tier that's free forever with no credit card required. It only takes a few clicks to launch a cluster. Cheers!